# How to check if one array elements entirely exists in another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, for example:

```
array1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
array2={4,6,9}
```

Is there any function so that I can determine that `array2` fully exists in `array1`?

I know i can use the `in_array()` function in a loop but in cases where I will have large arrays with hundreds of elements so I am searching for a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
$fullyExists = (count($array2) == count(array_intersect($array2, $array1));
```

The [**`array_intersect.php`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function will return only elements of the second array that are present in all the other arguments (only the first array in this case). So, if the length of the intersection is equal to the lenght of the second array, the second array is fully contained by the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for this, but you have to be a bit careful.

If the array to match has no duplicates, you can use

```
// The order of the arrays matters!
$isSubset = count(array_intersect($array2, $array1)) == count($array2);
```

However this will not work if e.g. `$array2 = array(4, 4)`. If duplicates are an issue, you need to also use `array_unique`:

```
$unique = array_unique($array2);
// The order of the arrays matters!
$isSubset = count(array_intersect($unique, $array1)) == count($unique);
```

The reason that the order of the arrays matters is that the array given as the first parameter to `array_intersect` must have no duplicates. If the parameters are switched around this requirement will move from `$array2` to `$array1`, which is important as it can change the behavior of the function.

Comment: This will force PHP to check for every value to determine if arrays are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy solution:

```
 array_diff(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),array(4,6,9));
```

if the return is a empty array, it is in the array otherwise he'll output the items that aren't

Comment: thank you for reply but it is not the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try with complex array but comparing work for me

```
var_dump(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) === array(4,6,9));
var_dump(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) === array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
```